# UV Problem when baking Highpoly to Lowpoly Mesh

Tags: uv

Whenever I create an object, such as a simple chair, I UV-unwrap it. Then I start working on the high poly mesh. But whenever I add more geometry, the uv doesn't seem to unwrap the same. This happens whenever I use things like subdivide or even sculpt mode.

The UV layout just get oddly distorted, so I can't really bake it onto the low poly mesh, or it would look weird and not uniform. I've never seen this happen to anybody else, like Blender Guru. They Just UV-unwrap both meshes, and the UV layouts neatly align with the high, and low poly meshes. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You do not need to unwrap your highpoly mesh. This would be quite counterproductive and completely against its purpose. Where did you get the idea that you should unwrap both meshes?

Comment: I just am a little unsure how to bake the high poly detail onto the low poly mesh, without the information that the high poly uv map would provide. But I will try to use just the one uv map like you suggested. Also, thank you so very much for responding! It means a lot to me!

Comment: I'm also not sure where i got the idea either...i guess it's just something i assumed i had to do..?

Comment: You get the highpoly details from the **highpoly mesh**, not from the UV map. The UV map only represents the layout of the surface of your lowpoly mesh, when you "iron" it onto a flat surface.